# What is more suitable for saving a list?

Tags: android, file, android-sqlite

I am developing an app where the user have two lists: one with countries and one with towns. The user insert values in the lists and lists are use just to show values on screen using an ArrayList. Where is more suitable to save the lists? In 2 .txt files or in 2 SQLite databases with 2 columns (id and name)? In this case, working with files would be faster than the database?

Comment: storing in db would be better, you will have more flexibility that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you're using SQLite, use one database with 2 tables.
- 2 text files will work too. Downsides: sorting / updating / etc will be significantly harder and not necessarily O(1).

So I would suggest [using SQLite](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db).

Comment: And if I use a database I will have, as I said, 2 columns: id and name. But here I have a little problem: if I have 3 countries and I delete one and the I want to add one more, my id, which is primary key autoincrement, doesn't update. And after I added the new country I have following ids: 1, 2, 4. How to update the id column after a remove? @orip

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to use firebase for such database functions .
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database 
Consider this as reference documentary

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `realm`

https://blog.realm.io/realm-for-android

http://blogs.quovantis.com/how-realm-is-better-as-compared-to-sqlite/

Although it may be a little bit difficult to use at first